# Magento 2 - exception log is missing since update to 2.4.4-p3

Tags: magento2

The exception.log is missing since 2.4.4 because magento made a huge mistake. It is only fixed by upgrading to 2.4.6 and there is no official patch.

How can I fix it myself?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was reported in the Magento Open Source repository: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/36054

The related commits: https://github.com/magento/magento2/search?q=ACP2E-1287&type=commits

Based on these official commits, you can create a patch file to apply to your Magento project. There is only one file that needs to be edited in order to apply the fix, which is **lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php**. However, this is the file for project which installed via git repository (normally for contributors). For normal projects (installed via composer), we need to change **vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php**.

The patch file content for Magento version 2.4.4 and 2.4.5:

```
diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php
index 1b8f7de..dc6c877 100644
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/Logger/LoggerProxy.php
@@ -99,6 +99,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function emergency($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->emergency($message, $context);
     }

@@ -107,6 +108,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function alert($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->alert($message, $context);
     }

@@ -115,6 +117,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function critical($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->critical($message, $context);
     }

@@ -123,6 +126,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function error($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->error($message, $context);
     }

@@ -131,6 +135,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function warning($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->warning($message, $context);
     }

@@ -139,6 +144,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function notice($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->notice($message, $context);
     }

@@ -147,6 +153,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function info($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->info($message, $context);
     }

@@ -155,6 +162,7 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function debug($message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->debug($message, $context);
     }

@@ -163,6 +171,22 @@ class LoggerProxy implements LoggerInterface, NoninterceptableInterface
      */
     public function log($level, $message, array $context = [])
     {
+        $context = $this->addExceptionToContext($message, $context);
         $this->getLogger()->log($level, $message, $context);
     }
+
+    /**
+     * Ensure exception logging by adding it to context
+     *
+     * @param mixed $message
+     * @param array $context
+     * @return array
+     */
+    protected function addExceptionToContext($message, array $context = []): array
+    {
+        if ($message instanceof \Throwable && !isset($context['exception'])) {
+            $context['exception'] = $message;
+        }
+        return $context;
+    }
 }
```

If you apply it as a composer patch, you should apply to the `magento/framework` composer package.
For instructions on how to apply composer patches, please refer to this document: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html?lang=en#composer

Comment: I tried to apply your patch and followed all the instructions, but it fails.
Could not apply patch! Skipping. The error was: Cannot apply patch patches/composer/github-issues-36054.diff

Comment: @Black I've tested this patch file with 3 approaches: composer patch plugin (`composer install`), patch (`patch < patches/composer/github-issues-36054.diff`), and git apply (`git apply patches/composer/github-issues-36054.diff `. It works as expected. Can you try these commands to test the file patch in your environment?

Comment: You can try to run `composer install -vvv` command, it will displays debug verbosity.